# Bootstrap 3 check all on all page button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am using a bootstrap table with `data-filter` and `checkbox` column for selecting all.

I want to know that if there is any method or event in bootstrap table which selects all records on all page.

Also if I filter data with some `fields` and click on select all it should select all filtered data.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r6g4cfu/3/)

If I search for data and click on check all it should select all data on all page.

For now I have used another simple `html` button which selects all data from table without filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `responseHandler` option to solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4r6g4cfu/354/. 
Documentation here: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/